# The purpose of 'paragraph' function

Tags: paragraphs, semantics

A not so obvious function for me. Does this thing solely exist so that some paragraph could be placed in ToC? Anyway, what's about it? When should I use it and when not to? My guess is that it simply should be used under `\subsubsection` as if `\paragraph` would be called `\subsubsubsection`.

Comment: Yes. `\paragraph` is simply equivalent to the nonexistent `\subsubsubsection`,  It was a decision of LaTeX's creator never to have more tnan two "sub" levels.to a division of a document.

Comment: add `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}` to more clearly see that `\paragraph` is a section command, they will then be numbered being reset every subsubsection

Comment: Read the manual (Leslie Lamport, "LaTeX user's guide and reference manual") section 2.2.3 "Sectioning". It is usually usefull to read the manual before asking a question --- GOM